# Gem in Rails not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to use the symbolize gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/symbolize) with my Rails project. I added

```
gem 'symbolize', '4.2.0'
```

to my Gemfile and ran `bundle install`. If I run `gem list --local` I see the installed gem.

However, when I actually try to use the methods added to ActiveRecord by the gem I'm getting an error at runtime. I.e., I have:

```
class WrittenEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  symbolize :entry_type, :in => [:blog, :vorfreude, :twitter], :i18n => false
end
```

Which throws:

```
/Users/haldimann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing': undefined method `symbolize' for #<Class:0x007ff7ee8ad570> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/haldimann/Projects/nikhaldimann.com/app/models/written_entry.rb:4:in `<class:WrittenEntry>'
    from /Users/haldimann/Projects/nikhaldimann.com/app/models/written_entry.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/haldimann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/haldimann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/haldimann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/haldimann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/haldimann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/haldimann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /Users/haldimann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /Users/haldimann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    ...
```

It appears that the symbolize gem is somehow never actually loaded. I might be missing something obvious, any ideas?

Comment: Added issue for same problem at github: https://github.com/nofxx/symbolize/issues/41

Comment: According to that GitHub issue, it seems like the issue may be fixed in the latest version of symbolize. Could you update to 4.3.0+ and see if that fixes it?